# Parameter Name in Remote Model Validation Action of MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, remote-validation

I use Remote validation attribute for `SSN` property, In view Page I use generic view then the ssn field is like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainModel.SSN)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainModel.SSN)
```

and My Action is:

```
public JsonResult IsValidaSSN(string SSN) {

  //....

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

but always `SSN` is null in action, I also try `MainModelSSN`, `MainModel_SSN` but no change and always is null, what is your suggestion? what is the correct name for `MainModel.SSN` in action argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try specifying a prefix:

```
public Action IsValidaSSN([Bind(Prefix = "MainModel")] string SSN) 
{
    //....
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

`MainModel` is the prefix that is used to send the data => `MainModel.SSN`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the SSN is null yet.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. It worked when I tested it. What's the name used for the AJAX request?

Comment: what do you mean of Ajax request? how can I find the name?

Comment: The Remote attribute sends an AJAX request. So look in your javascript debugging tool. For example in FireBug all AJAX requests are listed. You could inspect the request and see exactly the payload being sent to the server.

Comment: In FireBug in params Tab is: MainModel.SSN 5896412571

Comment: I ask another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562810/blind-perfix-not-worked-in-remote-validation-action

Answer (score 4):

Another, slightly more precise, take on Rahul's answer:

```
public JsonResult IsValidImageUrl(string SSN) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SSN)) {
        string parmname = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.EndsWith(".SSN"));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parmname)) {
            SSN = Request.QueryString[parmname];
        }
    }

    //.... etc.
```

This can fly with multiple parameters.

Side note, you probably want to reconsider the association of a "GET" JSON method with anything associated with SSN's.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by just using the first query string parameter:

```
public JsonResult IsValidImageUrl(string value) {

    if (value == null && Request.QueryString.Count == 1) {
            value = Request.QueryString[0];
        }


    //....            

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                    
}
```

Comment: This method works nicely for simple child models that are shared on multiple models resulting in multiple bind prefixes. I'm using it on my PostalCode validation model.

Comment: I wound up doing something similar.  I removed the parameter entirely and always get the first QSP (error on `Count != 1`).  This makes sense because if you're using MVC validation you'd want to be able to apply this same code to many different fields in different forms.  Perhaps they do not share the same prefix or property name.  For these, the more generic the better I think.