# Bind Prefix not worked in Remote validation Action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I ask a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562261/parameter-name-in-remote-model-validation-action-of-mvc3). This is My Model:

```
[DisplayName("National Code")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[RegularExpression(CustomRegex.SSNRX, ErrorMessage = CustomRegex.SSNErMsg)]
[Remote("DBValidateSSN", "CustomerProfile", "Members", ErrorMessage = "Repeated.")]
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

So I use a Generic Class as a Model And My View is like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainModel.SSN)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainModel.SSN)
```

And Validate Action:

```
public JsonResult DBValidateSSN([Bind(Prefix = "MainModel")] string SSN) {

  // ....
  return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But the SSN parameter in action is always null, where is my fault? what is the problem I also check Ajax Request Params in FireBug and name used is `MainModel.SSN`, what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public ActionResult DBValidateSSN([Bind(Prefix = "MainModel.SSN")] string SSN)
{
    // ...
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```